# iOS Mail - Bad Rendering of Attachment Buttons - Any Solution?

Tags: ios, email, email-attachments

I've created a HTML email which I'm sending from a .NET site, and the email for the most part is rendering fine. However, in iOS Mail (on the iPhone and iPad), the attachment button the app adds at the bottom of the email renders in an extremely unattractive way. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Notice the overlapping and the cut off. It is happening in iOS 7, but it's not great in iOS 6 either. I've seen it occur before in emails received from others, but this is the first time I've seen it appear in my own.

I've checked the HTML is valid (ie: no unclosed tags, etc) and there isn't really anything unusual going on - the HTML is just some nested tables.

So does anyone know what is going on and how to solve (or at least mitigate) it? Or is this just a general quirk/bug of Mail that can't be solved?

Comment: How are the attachments added to the email? Are you sure your sever is generating a proper multi-part email? The attachment and HTML message body should be completely separate parts.

Comment: I'm just using the well documented MailMessage/SmtpClient APIs in .NET, and adding a file to the Attachments collection. The attachment opens fine and has no issues in any other mail client - it even opens fine in Mail. It's just the rendering of the open button which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue in iOS 7.03-7.04 (possibly prior too). After much troubleshooting, it appears that is the html content's width exceeds 360px, the Tap to Download attachment boxes begin to overlap. I have asked Apple for support on this and am awaiting a response. The width of the html content should have no effect on how the attachments are displayed, but it does. Does anyone else know of a fix for this?  I have emailed reports with multiple columns that cause this to occur. I have included a few cropped screenshots of the overlapping. Included in my support request at Apple is this post so if anyone else is experiencing this issue, please post your details here.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e651pa6mjxq485e/ios7_email_width_overlapping.jpg

Comment: I'm so glad it's not just me - I thought I was going mad. Good to know this extra info... mine is using a 100% width table container, but some of the internal nested tables have a fixed width of >360px, so this may be a similar scenario. Did you have a specific place you were contacting Apple through? I'd like to contribute if possible.

Comment: We have the same issue with an email generated using the Java client. Did you get to a solution on this?

Comment: I have the same issue when the phone is rotated to landscape, the attachment button starts to overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but we were just this week running into the same type of issue. The iOS mail app would end up overlapping the download button for our attachment with part of our email signature, and on some devices/orientation it would make the download button un-clickable.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46667752/493557) did the trick for us, by adding the following into the header of the HTML email message:

```
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
```

Comment: Thank you!  Solved my issue with images being overlapped by following table contents!