# Apple Mail iOS 11 template sizing

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, email

I've been hunting around for a solution to my current issue so let me start with a template that has been dumped on my lap:

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
                <title></title>

                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name=”x-apple-disable-message-reformatting”>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <style>
                    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);
                    /*Calling our web font*/
                    /* Some resets and issue fixes */

                    #outlook a {
                        padding: 0;
                    }

                    body {
                        width: 100% !important;
                        -webkit-text;
                        size-adjust: 100%;
                        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }

                    .ReadMsgBody {
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                    .ExternalClass {
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                    .backgroundTable {
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        padding: 0;
                        width: 100%;
                        !important;
                    }

                    table td {
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                    }

                    .ExternalClass * {
                        line-height: 115%;
                    }
                    /* End reset */
                    /* Fix for Yahoo align center bug on desktop */

                    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
                        table {
                            border-collapse: collapse !important;
                        }
                        table {
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            table-layout: fixed !important;
                            margin: 0 auto;
                        }
                        table table {
                            table-layout: auto;
                            table-layout: fixed !important;
                        }
                        .hide-in-yahoo {
                            display: none;
                        }
                    }
                    /* Outlook fix */

                    table {
                        border-collapse: collapse !important;
                    }

                    table td {
                        border-collapse: collapse !important;
                    }

                    .hide-button-div div {
                        display: none !important;
                    }
                    /* These are our tablet/medium screen media queries */

                    @media screen and (max-width: 630px) {
                        /* Display block allows us to stack elements */
                        *[class="mobile-column"] {
                            display: block;
                        }
                        /* Some more stacking elements */
                        *[class="mob-column"] {
                            float: none !important;
                            width: 100% !important;
                        }
                        /* Hide stuff */
                        *[class="hide"] {
                            display: none !important;
                        }
                        /* This sets elements to 100% width and fixes the height issues too, a god send */
                        *[class="100p"] {
                            width: 100% !important;
                            height: auto !important;
                        }
                        /* For the 2x2 stack */
                        *[class="condensed"] {
                            padding-bottom: 40px !important;
                            display: block;
                        }
                        /* Centers content on mobile */
                        *[class="center"] {
                            text-align: center !important;
                            width: 100% !important;
                            height: auto !important;
                        }
                        /* 100percent width section with 20px padding */
                        *[class="100pad"] {
                            width: 100% !important;
                            padding: 20px;
                        }
                        /* 100percent width section with 20px padding left & right */
                        *[class="100padleftright"] {
                            width: 100% !important;
                            padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
                        }
                        /* 100percent width section with 20px padding top & bottom */
                        *[class="100padtopbottom"] {
                            width: 100% !important;
                            padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
                        }
                    }

                    @media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
                        *[class].w320 {
                            width: 320px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].herobgresize {
                            background-size: 480px auto !important;
                            /* background-position:-160px 174px !important;*/
                        }
                        *[class].autoh {
                            height: auto !important;
                        }
                        *[class].wr {
                            display: block !important;
                        }
                        *[class].fl {
                            float: left !important;
                        }
                        *[class].herobg5 {
                            background-color: #86b0c6 !important;
                        }
                        *[class].font11 {
                            font-size: 11px !important;
                            line-height: 14px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].font13 {
                            font-size: 13px !important;
                            line-height: 16px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].font20 {
                            font-size: 20px !important;
                            line-height: 23px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].h5 {
                            height: 5px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].h8 {
                            height: 8px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].h10 {
                            height: 10px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].h15 {
                            height: 15px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].h20 {
                            height: 20px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].h35 {
                            height: 35px !important;
                        }
                        *[class].h {
                            display: none !important;
                        }
                        *[class].h160 {
                            height: 160px !important;
                        }
                    }
                </style>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body {
                        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
                        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
                        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
                    }

                    img {
                        border: 0 !important;
                        outline: none !important;
                    }

                    p {
                        Margin: 0px !important;
                        Padding: 0px !important;
                    }

                    table {
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        mso-table-lspace: 0px;
                        mso-table-rspace: 0px;
                    }

                    td,
                    a,
                    span {
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
                    }

                    .ExternalClass * {
                        line-height: 100%;
                    }

                    span.MsoHyperlink {
                        mso-style-priority: 99;
                        color: inherit;
                    }

                    span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
                        mso-style-priority: 99;
                        color: inherit;
                    }

                    .em_gray a {
                        color: #333333;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    .em_gray1 {
                        color: #808080;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    .em_gray1 a {
                        color: #f06060;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    .em_gray1 ul {
                        margin: 0px;
                        padding: 0px;
                        list-style-position: inside;
                        list-style-type: disc;
                    }

                    .em_gray1 ul li {
                        font: 14px #808080 Arial, sans-serif;
                        line-height: 20px;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }

                    .em_gray1 ul li a {
                        font: 14px #808080 Arial, sans-serif;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    .em_pink a {
                        color: #f06060;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    .em_whte a {
                        color: #ffffff;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    .em_white1 a {
                        color: #f1f4f5;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    center table {
                        width: 100% !important;
                    }

                    @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:649px) {
                        table[class=em_wrapper] {
                            width: 100% !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_hide],
                        table[class=em_hide] {
                            display: none !important;
                        }
                        img[class=em_full_img] {
                            width: 100% !important;
                            height: auto !important;
                            max-width: 100% !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_pad_top] {
                            padding-top: 20px !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_pad_bottom] {
                            padding-bottom: 20px !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_height] {
                            height: 20px !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_space] {
                            width: 15px !important;
                        }
                        table[class=em_wrapper_50_1] {
                            width: 50% !important;
                            max-width: none !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_center] {
                            text-align: center !important;
                        }
                    }

                    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
                        table[class=em_wrapper] {
                            width: 100% !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_hide],
                        span[class=em_hide],
                        table[class=em_hide] {
                            display: none !important;
                        }
                        img[class=em_full_img] {
                            width: 100% !important;
                            height: auto !important;
                            max-width: 100% !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_pad_top] {
                            padding-top: 20px !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_pad_bottom] {
                            padding-bottom: 20px !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_height] {
                            height: 20px !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_space] {
                            width: 15px !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_white] {
                            height: 20px !important;
                            background-color: #ffffff !important;
                        }
                        td[class=em_center] {
                            text-align: center !important;
                        }
                        table[class=em_wrapper_50_1] {
                            width: 50% !important;
                            max-width: none !important;
                        }
                    }

                    .regulatoryLogoContainer .regulatoryLogoItemContainer {
                        display: inline-block;
                        padding: 0 14px 15px
                    }

                    .BWL-mainFooter__lower__licenseText {
                        display: inline-block;
                        padding-top: 15px;
                        padding-bottom: 30px;
                        width: 100%;
                        text-align: center;
                        font-size: 12px;
                        color: #6d6d6d;
                    }

                    .BWL-mainFooter__partsDivider {
                        margin: 15px 0;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid #6d6d6d;
                    }
                </style>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  <style>ul{margin: 0 0 0 30px !important; padding: 0 !important; list-style-position: inside;}ul li{font: 14px #808080 Arial, sans-serif; color:#808080 !important; text-decoration:none !important; margin: 0 0 0 30px; padding: 0; list-style:disc;}ul li a{font: 14px #808080 Arial, sans-serif; color:#808080 !important; text-decoration:none !important; line-height:20px;}</style>
                  <![endif]-->
                <style type="text/css">
                    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */

                    body,
                    table,
                    td,
                    a {
                        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
                        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
                    }
                    /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */

                    table,
                    td {
                        mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
                        mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
                    }
                    /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */

                    img {
                        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
                    }
                    /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */
                    /* RESET STYLES */

                    img {
                        border: 0;
                        height: auto;
                        line-height: 100%;
                        outline: none;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    table {
                        border-collapse: collapse !important;
                    }

                    body {
                        height: 100% !important;
                        margin: 0 !important;
                        padding: 0 !important;
                        width: 100% !important;
                    }
                    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */

                    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
                        color: inherit !important;
                        text-decoration: none !important;
                        font-size: inherit !important;
                        font-family: inherit !important;
                        font-weight: inherit !important;
                        line-height: inherit !important;
                    }
                    /* MOBILE STYLES */

                    @media screen and (max-width: 525px) {
                        /* ALLOWS FOR FLUID TABLES */
                        .wrapper {
                            width: 100% !important;
                            max-width: 100% !important;
                        }
                        /* ADJUSTS LAYOUT OF LOGO IMAGE */
                        .logo img {
                            margin: 0 auto !important;
                        }
                        /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
                        .mobile-hide {
                            display: none !important;
                        }
                        .img-max {
                            max-width: 100% !important;
                            width: 100% !important;
                            height: auto !important;
                        }
                        /* FULL-WIDTH TABLES */
                        .responsive-table {
                            width: 100% !important;
                        }
                        /* UTILITY CLASSES FOR ADJUSTING PADDING ON MOBILE */
                        .padding {
                            padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
                        }
                        .padding-meta {
                            padding: 30px 5% 0px 5% !important;
                            text-align: center;
                        }
                        .no-padding {
                            padding: 0 !important;
                        }
                        .section-padding {
                            padding: 50px 15px 50px 15px !important;
                        }
                        /* ADJUST BUTTONS ON MOBILE */
                        .mobile-button-container {
                            margin: 0 auto;
                            width: 100% !important;
                        }
                        .mobile-button {
                            padding: 15px !important;
                            border: 0 !important;
                            font-size: 16px !important;
                            display: block !important;
                        }
                    }
                    /* ANDROID CENTER FIX */

                    div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] {
                        margin: 0 !important;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>

            <body align="center" style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <div data-type="slot" data-key="pre_header" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="PREHEADER GOES HERE"></div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <div data-type="slot" data-key="account_header" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="ACCOUNT LOGIN GOES HERE"></div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <div data-type="slot" data-key="top_right_ctas" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="TOP RIGHT CTA"></div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <div data-type="slot" data-key="logo_block" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="LOGO BLOCK"></div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <div data-type="slot" data-key="menu_bar" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="MENU BAR"></div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0px;mso-table-rspace: 0px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                        <div data-type="slot" data-key="bodycopy" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="PUT BODY COPY HERE"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0px;mso-table-rspace: 0px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                        <div data-type="slot" data-key="termsblock" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="PUT TERMS HERE"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0px;mso-table-rspace: 0px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                        <div data-type="slot" data-key="licensetext" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="PUT LICENSE HERE"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0px;mso-table-rspace: 0px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                        <div data-type="slot" data-key="legallogos" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="PUT LEGAL LOGOS HERE"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                           <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="640">
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0px;mso-table-rspace: 0px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                        <div data-type="slot" data-key="footer_section_" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="PUT FOOTER HERE"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                           <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking" /> </body>

            </html>
```

Now the issue I am having seems to be possibly with email sizing within Apple Mail on iOS 11 on the iPhone 7 + 8. Although this template seems to look ok in all clients, the result I am getting in Apple Mail looks a little something like this:

[image: iPhone 8 Apple Mail (iOS11)]

As you can see, the template isn't scaling up to the full width of the screen although, all the blocks are reacting exactly as they should be (this is what tells me it's a template issue and also sizing rather than alignment).

As I said, I've looked elsewhere for an answer but, on seem to find fixes for alignment and I'm starting to go a little crazy trying to figure out what it wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally arrived at an answer for this:

The media queries were causing a problem here. Having them separated between two  tags was the issue in this case and once they were stacked together the email returned to being responsive within Apple Mail.
There were no other changes needed.

I hope this helps others, it wasn't overly obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried x-apple-disable-message-reformatting without "smart quotes" ?

instead of:

```
<meta name=”x-apple-disable-message-reformatting”>
```

try:

```
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same issue, but this meta tag (introduced with iOS10) seems to do the trick:

```
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
```

source:
https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6871-ios-11-rendering-my-email-1-2-the-width-of-the-screen

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one of these to your `head` section:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">`

or

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`

Comment: Neither solution worked unfortunately. I had already inserted <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1> so also edited that but, no change